# Grabbing the first [x] characters for a string from a pipe

Tags: command-line, shell, text-processing

If I have really long output from a command (single line) but I know I only want the first [x] (let's say 8) characters of the output, what's the easiest way to get that? There aren't any delimiters.

Answer (score 172, accepted):

One way is to use `cut`:

```
 command | cut -c1-8
```

This will give you the first 8 characters of each line of output.  Since `cut` is part of POSIX, it is likely to be on most Unices.

Comment: Note that `cut -c` selects characters; `cut -b` or `head -c` selects bytes. This makes a difference in some locales (in practice, when using UTF-8).

Comment: You also don't have to specify the start index in this case. Saying `cut -c-8` will select from character 1 to 8.

Comment: @Steven, `cut`'s equivalent on Windows is?

Comment: Also `command | dd bs=8 count=1 2>/dev/null`. Not saying it's shorter or superior. Just another alternative.

Comment: @Gilles, but note that with current versions of GNU `cut`, `cut -c` works like `cut -b` (that is, it doesn't work properly for multi-byte characters).

Answer (score 49):

These are some other ways  to get only first 8 characters.

```
command | head -c8

command | awk '{print substr($0,1,8);exit}' 

command | sed 's/^\(........\).*/\1/;q'
```

And if you have bash

```
var=$(command)
echo ${var:0:8}
```

Comment: I think the following sed formulation is a bit easier to read: `command | sed 's/\(.\{8\}\).*/\1/'` or if your sed supports it: `command | sed -r 's/(.{8}).*/\1/'`; Otherwise, +1

Comment: Good stuff, but note that `head -c` counts _bytes_, not characters. Similarly, among the major Awk implementations, only _GNU_ awk handles multi-byte characters correctly - FreeBSD Awk and Mawk do not.

Answer (score 16):

Another one liner solution by using [**Shell parameter expansion**](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

> `echo ${word:0:x}`

```
EG: word="Hello world"
echo ${word:0:3} or echo ${word::3} 
o/p: Hel


EG.2: word="Hello world"
echo ${word:1:3}
o/p: ell
```

Comment: You can also use a variable holding the length, e.g.: `x=8; echo ${word:0:$x}` instead of hard-coding the integer.

Comment: worth noting this will not be possible in ksh88, only 93

Comment: @Cometsong Testing with the Bash shell that came with "Git for Windows", it looks like you don't need to prefix x with the $ sign in this case: 

`x=8; echo ${word:0:x}` will work the same.

Comment: The source you're linking to does not describe the construct you used.

Comment: @zrajm Corrected the link.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a sufficiently advanced shell (for example, the following will work in Bash, not sure about dash), you can do:

```
read -n8 -d$'\0' -r <(command)
```

After executing `read ... <(command)`, your characters will be in the shell variable `REPLY`. Type `help read` to learn about other options.

Explanation: the `-n8` argument to `read` says that we want up to 8 characters. The `-d$'\0'` says read until a null, rather than to a newline. This way the read will continue for 8 characters even if one of the earlier characters is a newline (but not if its a null). An alternative to `-n8 -d$'\0'` is to use `-N8`, which reads for exactly 8 characters or until the stdin reaches EOF. No delimiter is honored. That probably fits your needs better, but I don't know offhand how many shells have a read that honors `-N` as opposed to honoring `-n` and `-d`. Continuing with the explanation: `-r` says ignore `\`-escapes, so that, for example, we treat `\\` as two characters, rather than as a single `\`.

Finally, we do `read ... <(command)` rather than `command | read ...` because in the second form, the read is executed in a subshell which is then immediately exited, losing the information you just read.

Another option is to do all your processing inside the subshell. For example:

```
$ echo abcdefghijklm | { read -n8 -d$'\0' -r; printf "REPLY=<%s>\n" "$REPLY"; }
REPLY=<abcdefgh>
```

Comment: If you just want to output the 8 chars, and don't need to process them in the shell, then just use `cut`.

Comment: Good to know about `read -n <num>`; small caveat: Bash 3.x (still current on OS) mistakenly interprets `<num>` as a _byte_ count and thus fails with multi-byte characters; this has been fixed in Bash 4.x.

Comment: This is a great and useful answer. Much more general than the others.

Comment: On my git bash, I have the "-N" flag, which reads exactly N chars until EOF or timeout. Isn't that what you try to achieve your "d" flag ?

Comment: @Itération122442 yes but as I wrote "I don't know offhand how many shells have a read that honors -N as opposed to honoring -n and -d."

Comment: Whoops. Mea culpa. Missed that part.

Comment: `-d$'\0'` is the same as `-d` in bash. bash doesn't support passing NULs to commands, even builtin ones. You'd need `-d ''`. `-d ""`, `-d $''`, `-d $'\0'`, `-d $'\u0000'`, `-d $'\x0'`, `-d $'\0\0\0\0'` would also work but they're all the same in bash, so using those `\0`s there would be misleading. See also [my answer](/a/758188) for hints at other problems in that code.

Answer (score 2):

This is portable:

```
a="$(command)"             # Get the output of the command.
b="????"                   # as many ? as characters are needed.
echo ${a%"${a#${b}}"}      # select that many chars from $a
```

To build a string of variable length of characters has [its own question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3211891/2350426).

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem when manually generating checksum files in maven repository.
Unfortunately `cut -c` always prints out a newline at the end of output.
To suppress that I use `xxd`:

```
command | xxd -l$BYTES | xxd -r
```

It outputs exactly `$BYTES` bytes, unless the `command`'s output is shorter, then exactly that output.

Comment: another method to take off `cut`'s trailing newline is to pip it into: `| tr -d '\n'`

Answer (score 1):

**How to consider Unicode + UTF-8**

Let's do a quick test for those interested in Unicode characters rather than just bytes. Each character of `áéíóú` ([acute accented vowels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acute_accent)) is made up of two bytes in UTF-8. With:

```
printf 'áéíóú' | LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 awk '{print substr($0,1,3);exit}'
printf 'áéíóú' | LC_CTYPE=C awk '{print substr($0,1,3);exit}'
printf 'áéíóú' | LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 head -c3
echo
printf 'áéíóú' | LC_CTYPE=C head -c3
echo
```

we get:

```
áéí
á
á
á
```

so we see that only `awk` + `LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8` considered the UTF-8 characters. The other approaches took only three bytes. We can confirm that with:

```
printf 'áéíóú' | LC_CTYPE=C head -c3 | hd
```

which gives:

```
00000000  c3 a1 c3                                          |...|
00000003
```

and the `c3` by itself is trash, and does not show up on the terminal, so we saw only `á`.

`awk` + `LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8` actually returns 6 bytes however.

We could also have equivalently tested with:

```
printf '\xc3\xa1\xc3\xa9\xc3\xad\xc3\xb3\xc3\xba' | LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 awk '{print substr($0,1,3);exit}'
```

and if you want a general parameter:

```
n=3
printf 'áéíóú' | LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 awk "{print substr(\$0,1,$n);exit}"
```

Question more specific about Unicode + UTF-8: https://superuser.com/questions/450303/unix-tool-to-output-first-n-characters-in-an-utf-8-encoded-file

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405611/how-to-extract-the-first-two-characters-of-a-string-in-shell-scripting

Tested on Ubuntu 21.04.

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`, you can do:

```
cmd | read -u0 -k4 -e
```

`read` will read as many bytes as needed to read 4 characters (`k` was initially for `k`ey, but with `-u` specifying a file descriptor it reads *characters* from there instead of key presses from the terminal) and echo (`-e`) those characters on stdout. You can change `-e` to a variable name to read those bytes into a variable.

`ksh93` later (in ksh93o in 2003, while zsh's `-k` is from the 90s) added a `-N` options as an equivalent of `zsh`'s `-k` which was later copied by `bash` (though with some differences, see below). It doesn't have an equivalent for `-e` though.

```
cmd | read -N4 var
```

Contrary to `zsh`, `ksh93` cannot store NUL characters in its variables, and more generally, it will fail in random ways if there are NULs in its input.

Now, besides `-N`, `ksh93` also has a `-n x` option which reads up to `x` characters from a line, and the record delimiter can be changed with `-d`, and with recent versions of ksh93u+m, `-d ''` is for NUL-delimited records.

So:

```
cmd | read -d '' -n 4
```

there fails in a less random way if the input contains NUL characters: it just stops at the first NUL.

Now, bash copied all of `-n`, `-N`, `-d` (including `-d ''`) from ksh93 but with important differences:

- it still does backslash processing when `-n`/`-N` are specified, so you need `-r` to work around it as usual.
- it still does `IFS` processing, which you need to work around by calling it as `IFS= read...` as usual
- it skips all NUL characters in its input
- by default, the last component of a pipeline also runs in a subshell, which you can work around by using a redirection to a process substitution.

So in bash, you'd do:

```
IFS= read -rN4 var < <(cmd)
```

To read the first non-NUL characters of the output of `cmd` or (if `cmd` is `cat /dev/zero`, it will never return). And:

```
IFS= read -d '' -rn4 var < <(cmd)
```

To read 4 characters up to the first NUL.